# Run a script with debug log created along

Tags: shell-script

I am running a shell script which invokes two scrips within, in a sequence on two other systems using scp and ssh.

I need to print the output of the two scripts within the main script to the screen however for debugging i would like to have output similar to `sh -x <script.sh>` somewhere on a file.

Is there a way to achieve this without breaking the standard output messages for the user ?

Comment: `sh -x` writes to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Are you suggesting i should use it probably this way ? sh -x <script.sh> 2>somefile.log ?

Comment: That could work... you could also add in `script.sh` a line in the beginning like `exec 2>>file.log`